# Нужно ли ставить тире в начале каждого абзаца речи одного лица?

Tags: тире, прямая-речь, оформление-текста, диалог, абзац

У меня в тексте романа один человек говорит долго, это выступление, семинар. Его реплики я выделяю отдельными смысловыми абзацами, чтобы не перегружать текст. Нужно ли в начале каждого абзаца ставить тире, хотя продолжается речь одного и того же героя? Например, 10 абзацев одного героя.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, тире ставится только один раз. В литературных произведениях используют три решения подобных ситуаций:

1) Просто пишут абзацы. Подразумевается, что ясно по контексту, кто говорит. Это самый неуклюжий, но наиболее популярный вариант.

2) Оформляют прямую речь при помощи кавычек или отступов (есть и другие варианты: курсив, шрифт, но это извращение). Редко встречается, но уже нагляднее.

3) Разбивают абзацы прямой речи авторскими вставками, либо репликами от других героев. Тогда мы имеем отдельные абзацы, которые можно выделять тире. Но это требует вмешательства в текст, его изменения. Пример из Дюма:

> — Узнав о том, Цезарь почел за благо укрыться не у одного из богатых
>   друзей, а у бедного крестьянина, которому некогда даровал хижину и
>   маленький сад; тот, храня благодарность, не пожелал ценой
>   предательства поменять их на большой сад и роскошные хоромы. А тем
>   временем все пытались замолвить словечко за опального: народ и знать,
>   всадники и сенаторы, не составляли исключения даже весталки. Все так
>   любили этого очаровательного юнца, который в свои двадцать лет набрал
>   уже тридцать миллионов сестерциев долгу и кому Красе… — Взгляните
>   туда, монсиньор: тот самый, что воздвиг эту прекрасную гробницу в
>   память о своей супруге…
>
> Путник указал посохом в сторону склепа Цецилии
>   Метеллы и продолжил:
>
> — …и кому Красе, скупейший из богачей, одолжил
>   пятнадцать миллионов, чтобы расплатиться с кредиторами. Те не давали
>   ему проходу и мешали уехать пропретором в Испанию, откуда Цезарь
>   возвратился, погасив все долги и имея на руках еще сорок миллионов… Но
>   Сулла не отступал: ему не терпелось уморить молодого человека. Как —
>   его мало волновало, главное — заполучить его голову, ни больше ни
>   меньше. Но тут появился один из давних друзей диктатора, тоже некогда
>   внесенный в проскрипции вместе с самим Суллой.

Но чаще всего мне попадается прямая речь в одном абзаце, сколь бы длинным он ни был. Конечно, это выглядит не эстетично, не реалистично, а читать такое невыносимо. Но это уже к разговору о уровне писательского мастерства в принципе.

Рекомендую в качестве образца интересно поданных длинных речей изучить монолог профессора Преображенского из "Собачьего сердца". Вот где это реализовано действительно не скучно и изобретательно.

А вообще пользуйтесь поиском по форуму. Такой вопрос точно был. Многие из тех, что Вам ещё придут в голову, тоже здесь наверняка разобрали.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы очень мне помогли.

Comment: @Станислав в таком случае можете принять ответ при помощи галочки.